# Will you recommend beginners to use Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a beginner in android development. Google announced [android studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#download). Will you recommend me to use it or sticking to eclipse makes sense for now.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Will you recommend me to use it

**UPDATE**: At the 2014 Google I|O conference, Google upgraded Android Studio from "early access preview" to "beta". That, coupled with their lack of enthusiasm about Eclipse's long-term prospects, means that Android Studio is a far more attractive option, even for newcomers. This is not to say that newcomers will not experience problems, but rather that those problems may be worth it.

<strike>Not now.</strike>

If you have a year-plus of Android application development, and you wish to experiment with Android Studio during the "early access preview", go right ahead.

However, as was pointed out in the Google I|O sessions, Android Studio is very rough around the edges. Only people with enough experience to know when their problems come from Android Studio issues, versus other sources, should be trying to seriously use Android Studio at this time.

Once the "early access preview" label is taken off, then it should be safe for anyone, newcomers and experts alike, to use it.

Comment: Who can deny when CommonsWare himself says no :)

Comment: Arg ! I was just starting

Comment: I really like `Android Studio`, and look forward to it being mature.  As of right now though, I am going back to `ADT`.  [This problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16580776/1747491) and [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19597298/1747491) caused me to switch back.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm interested to know what is your opinion now about beginners getting started with Android Studio. Android Studio is still available as an early access preview, but it has been around for a year now.

Comment: @AmnaAli: I am less concerned than I was back then. There are more blog posts and the like to help newcomers. Personally, I still do not recommend newcomers dive into Android Studio until the "preview" label comes off, probably by Google I|O 2014. I am less worried about newcomers who try it anyway.

Comment: _Once the "early access preview" label is taken off, then it should be safe for anyone_ - Commonsware. OK, what about the Beta label?

Comment: @WilliamT.Mallard: Particularly given the fact that Google seems lukewarm about maintaining Eclipse, I am starting to steer people towards using the Android Studio beta.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Ware! This last ADT upgrade was, er, not so good.

Answer (score 8):

I would stick to Eclipse for now, seen as it has been around a lot longer so it would be less buggy. There are also loads of simple guides on how to use eclipse, Android Studio is only in its early stages and will be quite buggy and it might take a while to find out how to use it.

It really matters what you find easiest and it won't hurt to try them both out but in my solid opinion go with Eclipse for now until Google have released a stable version of there software.

Answer (score 4):

Since Android Studio was just recently announced, you'll have to wait see how other feel about it after some use.  It will probably come down to personnel preference. You should try them both out and see what YOU like best.