# Android Studio - Importing external Library/Jar

Tags: android, intellij-idea, dependencies, gradle, android-studio

I recently downloaded Android Studio to develop Android applications (I'm coming from Eclipse), and I am having issues using external libraries and/or external JAR files alongside my own project. **NOTE**: the following tests were conducted on a **new** application project created from scratch in Android Studio.

Example 1: JAR Import.

1. Download a fresh copy of the Admobs SDK from Google.
2. Copy the library jar `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar` to the project's /libs/ folder.
3. In the project explorer, right click on the newly added library.jar and click on 'Add as Library'.

Technically at this point **everything works**, imports work just fine, the layout editor shows a preview of the `AdView` widget and all that. The **only** problem is that it doesn't compile successfully.

Log from console:

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':APITests:compilePaidDebug'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
```

I tried running `gradlew compileDebug --stacktrace`, and the problem seems to be that the despite being able to import the classes successfully in both the code & design editor, at compile time, it cannot resolve the imports. Here's the relevant part of the log: ([full stacktrace here](https://gist.github.com/daniel-c05/a70a4b3551089cfd731b))

```
java:6: error: package com.google.ads does not exist
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;    
java:7: error: package com.google.ads does not exist
import com.google.ads.AdView;
java:11: error: cannot find symbol
AdView mAdView;
symbol:   class AdView
location: class MainActivity
java:22: error: cannot find symbol
mAdView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
symbol:   class AdView
location: class MainActivity
java:23: error: cannot find symbol
mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
symbol:   class AdRequest
location: class MainActivity
5 errors
:Test:compileDebug FAILED
```

But again, the imports work well in the editor, and the dependency is there:

[image]

It's also worth noting that without attempting to add a library/JAR, the projects compiles just fine.

I then tried editing the build.gradle file to include the new lib like this:

```
dependencies {
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar', 'libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar')
}
```

This time, it did compile successfully, but the app now forces closes, as apparently, it cannot find a specific class from the lib in the application package.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.ads.AdView" on path: /data/app/com.foo.test-1.apk
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried compiling with Gradle from the command line (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16657710/1217087) answer)?

Comment: I have a similar problem with the Gson library and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library solve my problem, more important the `clean` step

Answer (score 99, accepted):

So,

Steps to follow in order to import a JAR sucesfully to your project using Android Studio 0.1.1:

- Download the library.jar file and copy it to your /libs/ folder inside your application project.
- Open the build.gradle file and edit your dependencies to include the new .jar file:

`compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar', 'libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar')`

- File -> Close Project
- Open a command prompt on your project's root location, i.e `'C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplicationProject\'`
- On the command prompt, type `gradlew clean`, wait till it's done.
- Reopen your application project in Android Studio.
- Test run your application and it should work succesfully.

Comment: FYI, fileTree can be used to import all JARs in a directory. For example: `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')`

Comment: instead of editing the build.gradle file manually, you can just right-click on the jars in the project explorer and select "Add as Library"

Comment: The advice on closing AS, cleaning from command line and re-opening AS solved all my compilation problems!

Comment: Closing AS and running gradlew clean did it for me to.  You would think that sync gradle from within project would have.

Answer (score 31):

You don't need to close the project and go to command line to invoke grade:clean.
Go to Build-> Rebuild Project

Comment: i know eh.. my command line on mac didn't even recognize `gradlew`, and issuing `brew install gradle` is making me wait an hour for it to install.. kudos to you big man

Comment: gradlew is an executable located in the project root, you probably would have had to write `./gradlew` instead of simply `gradlew`.

Answer (score 16):

Easy way and it works for me. Using Android Studio 0.8.2.

1. Drag jar file under libs.
2. Press "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

**"simple solution is here"**

1 .Create a folder named **libs** under the app directory for that matter any directory within the project..

2 .**Copy Paste** your Library to **libs** folder

3`.You simply copy the JAR to your libs/ directory and then from inside Android Studio, right click the Jar that shows up under libs/ > Add As Library..`

Peace!

Comment: This works for me :) By far the simplest way of doing it.

Comment: This is an awsome solution :)

Comment: It was added automatically as a dependency in the project in intellij idea

Answer (score 10):

Here is how I got it going specifically for the *admob sdk jar* file:

1. Drag your `jar` file into the libs folder.
2. Right click on the `jar` file and select *Add Library*
   now the jar file is a library lets add it to the compile path
3. Open the `build.gradle` file (note there are two `build.gradle` files at least, don't use the root one use the one in your project scope).
4. Find the dependencies section (for me i was trying to the admob -GoogleAdMobAdsSdk jar file)
   e.g.

   ```
   dependencies {
      compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar','libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.3.1.jar')
   }
   ```
5. Last go into `settings.gradle` and ensure it looks something like this:

   ```
   include ':yourproject', ':yourproject:libs:GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.3.1'
   ```
6. Finally, Go to *Build -> Rebuild Project*

Comment: There is no Add Library menu item in Android Studio 0.2.5

Comment: Why is settings.gradle necessary here?  I don't think one needs to specify jars in settings.gradle!

Answer (score 2):

you export the project from Eclipse and then import the project from Android Studio, this should solve your problem, open a eclipse project without importing it from Android Studio you can cause problems, look at:
(Excuse my language, I speak Spanish.)
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: The two projects I'm testing with were not exported from Eclipse, they were both created from scratch with Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem not able to load jar file in libs folder in Android Studio.
If you have added JAR file in libs folder, then just open `build.gradle` file and save it without editing anything else. If you have added this line

`compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

save it and clean the project .. In next build time Android Studio will load the JAR file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Android Studio 0.5.2. So if your version is lower than mine my answer may not work for you.

3 ways to add a new Jar to your project:

1. Menu under **Files-->Project Structure**
2. Just press '**F4**'
3. under Project navigation, right clink on any java library and a context menu will show then click on '**Open Library Settings**'

A Project Structure window will popup.

On the left column click on 'Libraries' then look at the right pane where there is a plus sign '+' and click on it then enter the path to your new library.

Make sure the new library is under the 'project\libs\' folder otherwise you may get a broken link when you save your project source code.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using Android Studio 1.4.

For importing and adding libraries, I used the following flow ->

```
1. Press **Alt+Ctr+Shift+S** or Go to **File --> Project** Structure to open up the Project Structure Dialog Box.

2. Click on **Modules** to which you want to link the JAR to and Go to the Dependency Tab.

3. Click on "**+**" Button to pop up Choose Library Dependency.

4. Search/Select the dependency and rebuild the project.
```

I used the above approach to import support v4 and v13 libraries.

I hope this is helpful and clears up the flow.

Answer (score 0):

I use android studio 0.8.6 and for importing external library in project , paste that library in libs folder and inside build.gradle write path of that library inside dependencies like this
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio (mine is 2.3.1) go to File - Project Structure:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Check the libs version requirements. The lib might be trying to call a method from from a higher Android version. Try adding the apps compatability libs.

When all else fails try switching from a Gradle build to an Eclipse build.

Delete and restructure your folders to the eclipse style and delete everything but your code. Then reload the project with your libs.

Once it runs go back to Gradle, if you wish.