# intelliJidea plus Gradle, where can i find Compiler Ouput?

Tags: ide, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

Don't know if this is because android-studio does something wrong, or just common to all gradle projects in intelliJ, but sometimes when i run the build/debug, all I get is:

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ProjectA:compileDebug'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I can't seem to find any way to get more information, as this text already appear on what i consider to be the compiler output.

Where should I be looking at?

Comment: FYI: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16779959/104891) looks related.

Comment: @CrazyCoder indeed it is! I will digest it tonight and if it has the answer to this one i will document here as well! thanks

Comment: You should check this out and I found my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36977735/display-gradle-output-in-console-in-intellij-idea-2016-1-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I've done to get some better information is go to the project root via the command line and run

```
gradlew compileDebug
```

this does give more information, but I'm not 100% sure its running the same command as the IDE.

Comment: (and there goes reason number 312 of why i avoid IDEs...) Since Gradle is yet another build tools that i know nothing about for now... care to share the build command you use for a standard android studio project? Thanks!

Comment: In the root of your project use the command gradlew compileDebug

Comment: it was not the right output but got me closer... endedup removing the IDE and am restarting the project like it should have. thanks for the help

Comment: This is so stupid (the IDE, not your solution). I mean, if you can't even see the error list, why should someone use intelliJ over ecliplse for android?

Comment: Hey, FYI, the immediate culprit here is gradle, not the IDE.