# Display Gradle output in console in Intellij IDEA 2016.1.1

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

When running Gradle task from IDEA:

[image: IDEA Gradle window]

console output looks like:

[image]

As one can see, `bootRun` task failed. But I can't find the reason of the fail.

Is there a way to make Gradle output be displayed in Intellij Console when starting tasks from Gradle window?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

You can click the icon marked in the image bellow

> Toggle tasks executions/text mode

That will switch to the console log of your build and you can see what went wrong.

[image]

**UPDATE:** As of 2019.2.3, you don't need to toggle task/console view as you can see now both at the same time:

[image]

Comment: I been working in command line for years already just because I didn't knew about this. LOL

Comment: Where is this button on Android Studio 2 or 3

Comment: This highlighted button does not show in Intellij IDEA 2019.2.3. Is there a different way to do the same in this version?

Comment: Now you can see both console output and steps at the same time by default. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I know it's so obvious that you don't need to tell about it.
But I've spent the whole day not getting what's going on)

If you cannot find logs, and see only Gradle steps, probably you just have to expand the logs window. Somehow it was minimized without my notice.

Added a screenshot just in case. Just drag the mouse pointer to the left on the spot circled in red.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @LexSav, this is exactly was happening, the expanded main panel was hiding the logs underneath. Thanks again.

Comment: @Amit, glad it helped! I remember I was so angry when I realized that I'd spent half a day on this

Answer (score 0):

In IDEA 2019.2.3 the icon has change. See circled icon in image:

[image]