# Is there an IntelliJ/Gradle log that contains this info?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have a Gradle project in IntelliJ 2016.2. For Gradle tasks I know [how to see the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36977735/display-gradle-output-in-console-in-intellij-idea-2016-1-1). But whenever I change something in my `build.gradle` file, IntelliJ starts do to some Gradle stuff in the background , like refreshing dependencies and building.

Is there a way to see the output of those tasks running in the background? (The tasks run fine without an error, and I'd prefer not to break them just to get some output somewhere.)

Comment: In Android Studio there is `Gradle Console`. https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html. There is no such window in Intellij IDEA by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the official support:

> Now, you can see the output in the `idea.log` file.

[image: Show log in explorer]

To access the log file refer to the manual: [Locating IDE log files](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)

See more: [Android Studio -> IntelliJ: "gradle console" missing, gradle compiler background task output](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206829945-Android-Studio-IntelliJ-gradle-console-missing-gradle-compiler-background-task-output?sort_by=votes)

Comment: This is really helpful