# Adding Samsung SDK to Android Studio project

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio, samsung-mobile, bluetooth-lowenergy

I tried adding the BLE SDK from Samsung into my Android Studio project. I followed the instructions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779959/android-studio-importing-external-library-jar), but I still get errors.

In my project folder I created a `libs` directory, where I put the `samsung_ble_sdk_200.jar`. I right clicked the file in Android Studio and chose to make a library out of it, and this shows in the project settings as okay. In my `build.gradle` I edited the `dependencies` section to

```
dependencies {
    compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0', 'libs/samsung_ble_sdk_200.jar')
}
```

and rebuild the project. I then get the error

```
Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':S4BLE'.
> The description libs/samsung_ble_sdk_200.jar is invalid
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you can follow the instructions in chapter 8 in this document.

Click [here](http://img-developer.samsung.com/contents/authCdn/ble/Guide_and_Hints_for_Samsung_BLE_API.pdf?__gda__=1377107877_940bc66e63d1850abf2c91605a7ef522) (invalid link)

Be also sure of the .classpath file is not hidden in your project folder, when adding your .jar file. It can typically be the issue.

Comment: unfortunately I can't. The UI in Android Studio for changing these preferences does not yet affect the actual build, so it has to be done manually by editing the apropriate build files.