# Trying to set up admob in Android Studio

Tags: android, admob, android-studio

I have been following this tutorial here:

[Android Studio - Importing external Library/Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779959/android-studio-importing-external-library-jar)

I downloaded the jar and placed it in my lib folder for my project. I then added this line to my build.gradle:

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar', 'libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar')
```

So my whole build.gradle file now looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
        compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar', 'libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar')
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

I then did a build->rebuild project and I got this error:

```
Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'freeBP'.
> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection) values: [file collection]
  Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong, so I can get ads to work in my free version of my app?

Comment: You are trying to compile libs jars inside of your buildscript block.  You need to do it outside.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're declaring the dependency in the wrong place. Try with this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try to follow the Following steps:-**

**1)** Check in the Sdk extras the Goolgle Play Service and Google repository is installed or not if not the install it.

**2)** Now make new Project and go to File->Project Structure->Dependencies->(+)com.google.android gms:play-service-ads:7.5.0

**3)** Go to Gradle Script and edit build.gradle(Module: app) this should look like this->

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lalit.firsttest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
}
```

**4)** Now change the Manifest File-->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lalit.firsttest" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**5)** Now go to Tools->Android->sync project with gradle files..
    hope this should work....