# Android studio not expanding AWS classes

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, mobile

I am using Android Studio 1.5 and trying to build an app which uses AWS cognito for authentication. I am in the initial stages of the build and referred [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/setup.html) AWS getting started guide.

When I am trying to import some of the AWS classes, I am getting the 'can't resolve **amazon**' error message in Android studio.

The libraries/classes I am trying to import are -

```
import com.amazon.identity.auth.device.AuthError;
import com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.api.AmazonAuthorizationManager;
import com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.api.AuthorizationListener;
import com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.api.AuthzConstants;
import com.amazon.identity.auth.device.shared.APIListener;
```

I referred the below earlier questions to resolve the issue, but still no progress..

[Android Studio - Importing external Library/Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779959/android-studio-importing-external-library-jar)

[Using Amazon Web Service SDK for Android in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481728/using-amazon-web-service-sdk-for-android-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those classes belong to [Login with Amazon](http://login.amazon.com/android) library. Please download the sdk [LoginWithAmazonSDKForAndroid.zip](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/lwa/sdk/LoginWithAmazonSDKForAndroid._TTH_.zip). Extract it and manually copy the login-with-amazon-sdk.jar under the lib directory to your project.

Comment: Thanks for the response Yangfan. I will try today and let you know.