# Android IOIO, Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ioio

I've dug up my old Android IOIO board and trying to write something basic on it again, through Android Studio, but apparently I can't even get "hello world" application right anymore... Neither Android- nor IOIO development is my coding "specialty", so please excuse the stupidness. If someone can please correct me?

I've started following [this tutorial](https://github.com/ytai/ioio/wiki/Building-IOIO-Applications-With-Gradle), but can't even get past the gradle build. So, first a screenshot of what I added where:

[image: cradle source file]

And respectively I'm sitting with the error:

Error:(15, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'IOIOTest'.

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.github.ytai.ioio:IOIOLibAndroid:5.05] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

By Googling this error, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311659/android-studio-gradle-could-not-find-method-compile) suggested something of 'gradlew clean', what I have no idea of?

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because "compile" is deprecated with gradle:3.0 and should be replaced by "implementation". Also you should place those dependencies inside the app module build.gradle file.

For a more detailed answer, have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493379/7728772

Comment: Thanks for the help Kai. That did the trick for the errors at least and got the app running. You don't maybe have a suggestion for a well-documented "updated" tutorial on the IOIO? All example projects look extremely dated, so for instance trying [this example](https://github.com/mitchtech/android_ioio_simple_digital_output/blob/master/src/net/mitchtech/ioio/SimpleDigitalOutputActivity.java), the code executed (didn't bomb out), but the LED toggling is non-responsive

Comment: Oh and, I suspect there's some problem in the manifest code. I tried to follow the manifest code in the example as closely as possible, but for some lines, code options (via intellisense) did for give the same give suggestions as presented in the example.