# ClassNotFoundException after restore from source control

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just restored a project from source control and my initial attempts to run it are failing. When I launch the app I get the following error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
>   com.mb.android.MB3Application: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Didn't find class "com.mb.android.MB3Application" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.mb.android-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mb.android-1,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

This project was working prior to an OS re-install.

An excerpt from my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mb.android"
android:versionCode="9"
android:versionName="1.0.8" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".MB3Application" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value="com.mb.android.activities.mobile.SearchResultsActivity"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

...
removed
...

</application>

</manifest>
```

The package declaration in MB3Application.java

```
package com.mb.android;


public class MB3Application extends Application implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
}
```

The package declaration in MainActivity.java

```
package com.mb.android.activities;


public class MainActivity extends BaseMB3Activity implements ServerLocatedListener {
}
```

From what I can tell everything is ok. Does anyone have any ideas where this ClassNotFoundException is coming from. Also, the project is being built using Android Studio.

Thanks.

EDIT: In response to an answer below. Here are how my libraries are set up.

I only have one module in the project. Here are it's libs. I've right-clicked on them and selected add as library where possible.

[image]

The external libraries section of the project.

[image]

The modules build.gradle dependencies

[image]

The dependencies listed in the project structure dialog

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically a Java Build Path issue:

- Check that you are not missing that .jar file from your 'libs' folder.
- Check the project build path.
- Check that library requiring being exported are exported.

[Android Studio - Importing external Library/Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779959/android-studio-importing-external-library-jar)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still not able to resolve this with that info. I've updated my original post with images. Hopefully you or someone else can elaborate.

Comment: It was a library that wasn't added properly. Thanks