# How to import the external libraries to target project's lib folder with Gradle

Tags: gradle

There is a transitive library that I need to use in my project, but it has transitive dependencies of several levels deep. I understand that by default all the required jar files will be automatically downloaded to the local repository, which is by default at **USER_HOME/.m2** folder (my OS is Windows).

Is there a way to import all the required jar files into another specified folder? I'm planning to put all the jar files inside the **'project_name/libs'** folder.

Basically, my question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779959/android-studio-importing-external-library-jar), but with transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Putting libraries in the folder is possible and can be configured as in [this](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#file-dependencies) tutorial. However if You use the local folder transitive dependencies will not be resolved - You need to put all the libraries in this folder if You'd like it to be the only repository for libraries. What You can do also is to exclude transitive dependencies as written [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#exclude-dependencies). The scenario is a bit unclear so I suppose that You probably need to use both approaches.

Comment: @IwanSatria, was this answer useful?