# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException

Tags: java, android, docx4j

I am building my android project when i got this error after import docx4j library in my project. What should i do to get rid of this exception.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640314/android-studio-fails-to-debug-with-error-org-gradle-process-internal-execexcepti

Comment: Please share your gradle build. Also if possible try running the same with `--info` or `--debug` to get more info

Comment: Nothing worked for me yet

Comment: I found this Git discussion helpful for me: https://github.com/facebook/rebound/issues/71

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had got the same error. But I resolved the issue by adding the     following missing line from build.gradle in dependencies.
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'

```
After adding this line, my dependencies body was like this:
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: "commons-io-2.4.jar")  }
```

You can match with yours too and see if it can help you too

Answer (score 47):

Add this to your file build. gradle

```
defaultConfig {
     multiDexEnabled true 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , there seems only one way you can solve this problem . I ask you from where you find it?(Google Translate)

Comment: some time ago I experienced the same error.

add this code compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' for pre-lolipop device

Comment: solves the problem but each compilation takes equal time to make a clean build.. :'(  ..It does not work for me, so I returned it to 7.21

Comment: Do i need to give it in the every module's gradle file of my applications. for example I am having 7 modules along with the main app module of my app?

Comment: @souttab, I think this is a gradle issue but +1 for sharing the solution and comment

Comment: Error:(23, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'defaultConfig()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'Buseeta' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>

Answer (score 9):

The Android plugin for Gradle available in Android SDK Build Tools 21.1 and higher supports multidex, so you have to add `multiDexEnabled true` to your gradle file like below :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Do i need to give it in the every module's gradle file of my applications. for example I am having 7 modules along with the main app module of my app?

Comment: Only setting "multiDexEnabled" true solves the problem, add that dependency is not needed

Answer (score 6):

I might need more information but according to the error on your question:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

The IntelliJ compilation way might cause the error you post (at least in my case, it does). I recently came from Eclipse, where a 'Clean Project' is made after every run. In IntelliJ, the project needs a clean build to be run. 
I've avoided cleaning every time, disabling incremental flag inside dexOptions of the build.gradle.

Comment: Cleaning the project and rebuilding solved the problem. For me, the error occurred when I moved the project from one PC to another.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem and I did add the `multiDexEnabled true` in build file but all in vain. But doing the following along with adding `multiDexEnabled true` in defaultConfig solved my problem.

Add the MultiDexApplication in your manifest like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And dont forget to add

```
defaultConfig {
     multiDexEnabled true 
}
```

The did the trick for me. Ref : [Android Studio fails to debug with error org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640314/android-studio-fails-to-debug-with-error-org-gradle-process-internal-execexcepti)

Answer (score 2):

the same as my error

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2enter code here`

it is because there is a duplication of its dependency lib, in my case like this

`compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`

then I fixed it to be like this
`compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`
remove other setting import lib

I hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

This Problem can easily be resolved by Removing multiple jar in your project libs folder.