# Android studio build failed with the following error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460443/execution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process-proces)

but my problem still not solved. How can i solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to enable MultiDex to fix 65k methods error by adding this to your build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Also check for duplicated libraries usage (sometimes multiple libraries use same dependency like support-v4)

Comment: have tried this..but it gives another error - Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/StyleableRes.class

Comment: I edited my answer, check if one of your libraries (usually support-v4) is being used by multiple dependencies. If so you can exclude this module from one of them!

Comment: hey found the solution. it was having multiple libraries using same dependency. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This error could occur if some of your jar files does not compile. You should go into your `build.gradle` file in your project, and look in your dependencies.

If you're just importing some jar files, you could try to remove them and add them one at a time. This will help you determine which one of them causes the error.

In my case, I did just that, and when I was importing the last one, the app compiled. So I think the real problem was that I was importing too many at once. But now it all works.

Other possible issue its dependency error, clean gradle before build