# android studio execution failed for task app dexdebug command finished with non zero value 1

Tags: java

My problem is this:
I just installed Google Android Studio and when i run the default program (the simple interface and that default java code) it gives me this error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

i am really new with android and i don't know what to do?
please help...

Comment: What "default" program were you using? It's not clear from your explanation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460443/execution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process-proces)

Comment: i mean the code that the google android studio has itself

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem solved it by adding two lines to the top of the build.gradle files:

**sourceCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7**

If you're using the experimental gradle plugin do this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
sourceCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

model {
    android {
        ...
```

Otherwise it's something like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    ...
```

*Make sure to go through all the build.gradle files and add the JavaVersion to any that have "model" or "android" in them

Comment: Issue is completely fixed by upgrading to the latest build of android studio and using **com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.0**

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, but fixed it. I assumed that everything was due to the Estimote library which I updated to a new version that comes in AAR format only.

Turns out, I had other dependencies being responsible for this. These did not cause any problems with the previous version that was a JAR.

In my case, I've included parse-bolts twice. Everything works great since I removed one of the lines in my build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me as well just after updating the Android studio.

I solved it by

1. "Build" --> "Clean Project"
2. "Build" --> "Rebuild Project"

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't add this library twice.