# How can i Solve this error in Android? (Finished with a non-zero Value)

Tags: android, android-resources

I cant seem to find what is wrong with my program with this error please

My code is long for me to post all my R. got red highlighted after i included this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

            TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("Please select a Level!");
            text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            text.setTextSize(15);

            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            // toast.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#DAAA"
    >
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/droid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

help

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: My code is fine only R. has an issue.

Comment: What is not clear in the error message? You 've created both `image.jpg` and `image.png`. They compete for the same name `R.drawable.image`

Comment: Not really my Drawable doesnt have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to check

1. Check if you image.jpg and image.png both in drawable folders.

if this is not case

2. Perform  **Build > Clean Project**

if still not resolved issue

3. **File > Invalidate Cache And Restart**

Comment: Number 3 helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

on your grandle file

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30982540/1651200)

Answer (score 0):

Find and delete jpg variants of your drawables (android studio can find it, so can you). Delete images.jpg, tryagain.jpg, etc.

Comment: I tried finding them but didn't locate them because as you can see they don't exist in my drawable.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Check your number of methods!

In my case, I included a big library (google play services) to my project and then the 65k method limit got exceeded.

Replacing it with the much smaller maps library fixed this problem.