# Getting Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, error-handling

I am using following dependencies in my build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
/*compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])*/
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.4'
compile project(':intercom-sdk-base')
compile project(':intercom-sdk-gcm')
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.3'
```

}

I have commented the line `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

To avoid mismatch but still getting following error :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'>
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero
>   exit value 2

Comment: Can u post the complete error message.

Comment: you can use `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'` instead of `1.11.0`

Comment: show error log & post `build.gradle` total.

Comment: add `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')` & open this `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Its needed to remove any dependency from above ?

Comment: @user5716019 Not yet . Did you set above mentioned ?? After change `clean-restart-Rebuild-gradle` .

Comment: Please try to check your resource, might be any resouce contain some error. OR try to add defaultConfig {
     multiDexEnabled true 
} in build.gradle

Comment: @user5716019 please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460443/execution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process-proces .Let me feedback

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have opened the comment and added as you suggested but, still getting same error.

Comment: @user5716019 okay , did you set `multiDexEnabled true` . Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: ya I have added it right now and its working now.. thanks

Comment: @user5716019 Move ahead .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `multiDexEnabled true` . Courtesy goes to **[multiDexEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests?answertab=active#tab-top)**

> The Android plugin for Gradle available in Android SDK Build Tools
>   21.1 and higher supports multidex as part of your build configuration. Make sure you update the Android SDK Build Tools tools and the Android
>   Support Repository to the latest version using the SDK Manager before
>   attempting to configure your app for multidex.

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion //Your Version
    targetSdkVersion //Your Version
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

**Call this in your dependencies**

```
  dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

**Advice**

You can use `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'`

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Restart-Sync`** your Project . Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

This happens quite frequently.

Just "Clean the project" -> "Rebuild the project", and you will be good to go.