# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am getting below error. How can I resolve this? There were questions asked regarding this, But that didn't worked for me.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mukesh.airpollution"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4'

}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}



dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Why two `com.android.support:appcompat`?

Comment: oh sorry, removed . But same problem is there.

Comment: `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` this line is also doubled and why include this `compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.3.jar')` if you're compiling `libs`??

Comment: updated, not working.

Comment: Look here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460443/execution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process-proces

Comment: @Aravind tried, not working

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

and

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

try removing one of them

Answer (score 0):

Change your build.gradle code to below code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mukesh.airpollution"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.3.jar')
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'


}
```