# How do I use a class from an imported jar file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I imported a jar file that I created with Eclipse to my Android Studio library but I don't know how to use the classes from it. [Imported it here and I'm now trying to use the logarithm class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs63z.png)

I tried to somehow get it with the import word on the beginning of a class but I don't get it to work. Sorry I'm a beginner. :p

Comment: Take a look at the link.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16818936/1855457

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok follow this:

1. Put the .jar into the libs folder
2. Put compile files('libs/your.jar') is in your build.gradle file (or compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar') if you are using many jar files)
3. Do a clean build (you can probably do this fine in Android Studio, but to make sure I navigated in a terminal to the root folder of my app and typed gradlew clean. If this does not work then use the terminal tab and do this: `gradlew clean`.

   Hope it helps!!!

Comment: I have done that so far. But how do I practically access a class from the lib in my code?