# How to add a Hamcrest library in an Android Studio project?

Tags: android, compiler-errors, dependencies

I'm working with my first project in **Android Studio 2.2**. When I try to **Sync the project with the Gradle**, it shows an error `error: package org.hamcrest does not exist`

Therefore I had downloaded the **hamcrest.jar** library and **added manually** it under myfirstproject\app\libs

But, I got the following error when I add **hamcrest.jar** to my project.

```
Could not find method compile() for arguments(file collection) on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DSL.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler
```

- This is my **build.gradle** file

  -

[image]

- Have I missed anything  during the installation of my Android Studio?
- Or should I need to add any libraries  to the project?
- If needed how it is to be done?

Comment: Did you made sure the library is under apps/libs?

Comment: also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779959/android-studio-importing-external-library-jar

Answer (score 3):

You added that to the wrong gradle file. Read the comment in that file that says not to add app dependencies there

Open app/build.gradle and you should notice that you already have

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

}
```

So, which means you don't have to add anything else to compile any jar files.

You really should not use a Jar file, though.

Add this

```
testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
```

Comment: But again occurred some errors..like "failed to resolve:javax.inject:javax.inject:1

Comment: I cant make my project

Comment: `javax.inject:javax.inject` is not anything in my answer. Please show both your Gradle files in your question as text, not images

Comment: 'Failed to resolve:junit:junit:4.12' what does it mean? Pls answer

Comment: I uninstalled my android studio and deleted all belonged files.Then downloaded a new android studio and installed.During my installation I had connected to a WiFi to download the required packages on time.Now my Gradle sync is completed successfully.

Answer (score 2):

**Hamcrest library is something that is automatically configured with Android Studio during the installation.**

Here the **error is due to the incomplete installation of Android Studio**. That is, most of the important external packages haven't get downloaded during the installation (including hamcrest.jar).This happened may be due to the **loss of network connection** at the time of installation.

---

So the **best solution** is

1. Uninstall the Android Studio,
2. Delete all the belonged files (AndroidStudioProjects,.AndroidStudio2.2 and .android folders ). **Don't forget** to move your current project to any other folder.
3. Once again install the Android Studio by making sure that you have a good network connection.
4. Open your last project from where it was moved
5. Sync the project with Gradle.

See that everything works fine!

Comment: Excellent point. Happened to me because I already had a project and AS instead of going through the wizard just opened the project. When I almost accidentally, out of frustration closed the project the wizard resumed and installed missing components