# Android Studio gradle failure on debug

Tags: java, android

Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':name:compileDebug'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: What does the compiler error output say?

Comment: I'm on android studio and i cant find it

Answer (score 0):

Try to run "gradlew compileDebug" from the command line to fix this problems. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16657710/1237841) answer for more information.

Also make sure to update your gradle plugin to the latest version. (0.4.3 since yesterday)
Use **com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.+** in your gradle.build file and you'll always get the latest gradle android plugin.