# gradlew: Permission Denied

Tags: gradle, android-studio, gradlew

I am attempting to run gradlew from my command line, but am constantly facing the following error.

```
Brendas-MacBook-Pro:appx_android brendalogy$ ./gradlew compileDebug --stacktrace
-bash: ./gradlew: Permission denied
```

I am already running this command from my project directory. Need to run this command as I am facing the same (nondescriptive) error on Android Studio 0.2.x as encountered here: [Android studio and gradle build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626026/android-studio-and-gradle-build-error)

Am I doing something wrong and how do I get around this?

Answer (score 1305, accepted):

Try to set the execution flag on your gradlew file:

`chmod +x gradlew`

Comment: is there some reason the default template doesn't already set gradlew as executable? it seems odd that i would have to do this.

Comment: I had similar issue when setting up Atlassian Bamboo build; checking the gradlew file out from git it didn't have the executable attribute so had to add a "script" task to my job to chmod +x as @Vincent pointed out. Thanks!

Comment: @Vincent could you please elaborate on why this is required to resolve the permission issue?

Comment: Simply said, the `x` flag tag the file as an executable, which the shell can launch.

Comment: @Abhijit you can check the file permissions by doing `ls -l`. This gives you the file permissions on the left-most column.

Comment: @DougAyers How you did configure Bamboo for Gradle based Android Project. I didn't find any direct support but there is option to write script but what I need to configure there ? Any suggestion please !

Comment: @DougAyers **chmod +x gradlew** worked for me. But this not generating any build output apk. Am I missing anything? Any suggestion !

Comment: Is this how is should be doing it?                                                                    
- run:
          name: Download Dependeuncies
          command: chmod +x gradlew androidDependencies

Comment: i got the same error. where should i set the set the execution flag. @Vincent

Comment: In the case that you have a git repo, do not forget to also `git update-index --chmod=+x ./gradlew`

Comment: In my case, this command doesn't work on my server (who said the container works the same in all docker servers? It's a big lie ).

I used the following command `RUN chmod 777 ./gradlew` and it works well.

Comment: For mac users, if the above command doesn't work, try running `chmod +x ./gradlew`

Comment: This is driving me mad, I've tried every solution I've found for this and nothing works. I went through the instructions here and followed them precisely: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-java-service

I used curl in WSL to create the project and copied them out into Windows from the explorer. I tried both chmod and git update-index. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Answer (score 203):

Could also be fixed with

```
git update-index --chmod=+x gradlew
```

Comment: proper fix for windows users. Thank you!

Comment: ... and commit and push are needed afterwards

Answer (score 77):

You need to update the execution permission for `gradlew`

**Locally**: `chmod +x gradlew`

**Git**:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x gradlew
git add .
git commit -m "Changing permission of gradlew"
git push
```

You should see:

```
mode change 100644 => 100755 gradlew
```

Comment: Thank You, "chmod +x gradlew" worked for me.

Answer (score 45):

You could use "bash" before command:

```
bash ./gradlew compileDebug --stacktrace
```

Answer (score 30):

Jenkins > Project Dashboard > (select gradle project) Configure > Build

**x** Use Gradle Wrapper

**Make gradlew executable x**

[image]

Comment: Does it work for you? I set the checkbox in my job's settings but it didn't lead to making gradlew executable. I use `clean before checkout` option.

Comment: Works for me! You have to tell jenkins explicitly to make the executable.

Answer (score 29):

on android folder cmd run

```
chmod +x gradlew
```

and run

```
./gradlew clean
```

and root project run

```
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 28):

Just type this `command` in **Android Studio Terminal** (Or your  Linux/Mac Terminal)

```
chmod +x gradlew
```

and try to :

```
 ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

[image]

Answer (score 21):

> git update-index --chmod=+x gradlew

This command works better especially on non-unix system.

Answer (score 8):

With this step set permission to **gradlew**

```
steps {
    echo 'Compile project'
    sh "chmod +x gradlew"
    sh "./gradlew clean build --no-daemon"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The **Solution** :

First, change the directory to android:-

```
cd android
```

After that, run this command

```
chmod +x gradlew
```

After that,

```
cd ..             // to get back to root folder
```

And then,

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 4):

If you face this error in Github actions, you need to add this step before ./gradlew assembleDebug:

```
  - name: Make gradlew executable
    run: chmod +x ./gradlew
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below command:

```
chmod +x gradlew && ./gradlew compileDebug --stacktrace
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue occur when you migrate your android project build in windows to any unix operating system (Linux). So you need to run the below command in your project directory to convert dos Line Break to Unix Line Break.

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix
```

If you dont have dos2unix installed. Install it using

In CentOs/Fedora

```
yum install dos2unix
```

In Ubuntu and other distributions

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the error is just a typo, using ***gradle*** instead of ***gradlew*** wrapper.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error trying to execute flutter run on a mac. Apparently, in your flutter project, there is a file android/gradlew that is expected to be executable (and it wasn't). So in my case,

```
chmod a+rx android/gradlew
```

i used this command and execute the project

Answer (score 1):

past it in your terminal:
chmod 755 android/gradlew.

Answer (score 0):

if it doesn't work after chmod'ing make sure you aren't trying to execute it inside the /tmp directory.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux Only

View > Tool Windows > Terminal

before

```
./gradlew.bat tasks
```

after

```
./gradlew tasks
```

eg

```
./gradlew dokkaHtml
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users facing this issue in android studio, change your terminal to cmd from Windows PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**:

- sudo nemo (or sudo nautilus)
- right click on the `gradle` directory
- go to the permissions tab
- give to all the permission to read and write
- press also the button "give permissions to sub directory and files"
- the same for the `.gradle` directory

Retry the gradle update.

Answer (score 0):

If that does not work, the second, and rarely found, way to solution this is to copy both files (gradlew and gradlew.bat) from a clean android project. (If your project is on react-native, I suggest to create a new react-native project that has the same version than your project then copy from it)