# Could not run adb reverse (React-Native)

Tags: android, shell, reactjs, react-native

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 2 mins 6.65 secs
>   Running C:\Users\arnold\AppData\Local\Android\sdk;/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.95.101:5555 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
>   Could not run adb reverse: spawnSync C:\Users\arnold\AppData\Local\Android\sdk;/platform-tools/adb ENOENT
>   Starting the app on 192.168.95.101:5555 (C:\Users\arnold\AppData\Local\Android\sdk;/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.95.101:5555 shell am start -n com.testproject/com.testproject.MainActivity)...

The build successful but it's not shown in GenyMotion emulator.

i running on Android 5.0.0 (API 21)

Comment: adb revese only works on Android 5.0+ devices https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577669/run-react-native-on-android-emulator

Comment: @LongfeiSong it's the real answer to me. thanks!

Answer (score 33):

You can click the device option button, or if it doesn't exist for your device use `adb shell input keyevent 82` command and select `Dev Settings` from menu, and then from the section `DEBUGGING` choose `Debug server host & port for device` and enter your PC's IP (you can find your IP from ipconfig command for Windows) for example `192.168.1.12:8081`.

after that, you can reload your application from options menu or restart your application.

Please pay attention:

- Your device and pc must be on the same network
- Host port can be found from node window, for example: `Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.`

**React-native option menu:**

[image: React-native option menu]

**Node window and successful Bundle loading**
[image]