# Could not run adb reverse: spawnSync React-Native ENOENT

Tags: android, react-native, reactxp

I am starting to code in ReactXP, and I need to get React-Native to work on Android device, but I am unable to test it, because error occured at the end of command `react-native run-android`. A also have my phone NExus 5X connected properly and I can see it through `adb devices`.

I think this happens, when command `react-native run-android` is running for 2 times and more, because when i used it first in my project, everything was ok, when I changed text in some component and ran command again, everything went wrong.

Here is a log at the end of output

```
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Nexus 5X - 8.1.0' for app:debug
Installed on 1 device.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 11.161 secs
Running sdk.dir=C:/Users/pc123/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 020b60af2344b558 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Could not run adb reverse: spawnSync sdk.dir=C:/Users/pc123/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb ENOENT
Starting the app on 020b60af2344b558
(sdk.dir=C:/Users/pc123/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 020b60af2344b558 shell am start -n com.rxptodolist/com.rxptodolist.MainActivity)...
```

SDK is located correctly, i had some errors earlier, but i already solved them, i also trid following steps from Stack Overflow posts, but still no luck - for example this [React Native adb reverse ENOENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835931/react-native-adb-reverse-enoent) or [Could not run adb reverse (React-Native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229579/could-not-run-adb-reverse-react-native)

OS Windows 10

Comment: It shouldn't matter, doesnt it loads the apk on your device ? Also uninstall the existing apk from your device before running this cmd.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your port 8081 is clean and ready to use.Check whether other services are listening to that port.try this
react-native start --port=8081

Answer (score 0):

Change the default port to 8088(or whatever port you like: just make sure it is not reserved like the port number 80 for HTTP) on yourApp\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\server\server.js. It will look something like this.

```
....
module.exports = {
  name: 'start',
  func: server,
  description: 'starts the webserver',
  options: [{
    command: '--port [number]',
    default: process.env.RCT_METRO_PORT || 8088,
    parse: (val: string) => Number(val),
  },
....
```