# Build failure: React Native Android

Tags: react-native

I am setting up my environment to start developing react native apps. I keep getting the following error:

> PS C:\map\development\learnreact\react-native\helloworld> react-native
>   run-android Starting JS server... Building and installing the app on
>   the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
>
> > Configure project :app Observed package id 'platform-tools' in inconsistent location
> >     'C:\Users\bheka\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools' (Expected
> >     'C:\Users\bheka\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\platform-tools')
> >     Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 in
> >     C:\Users\bheka\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\licenses
> >     Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 not
> >     accepted. Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 26 in
> >     C:\Users\bheka\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\licenses
> >     Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 26 not accepted.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
>   > Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
>   >      platforms;android-26 Android SDK Platform 26
>   >      build-tools;27.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3   To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing
>   >     components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.   Alternatively, to
>   >     transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see
>   >     http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html   Using Android
>   >     SDK: C:\Users\bheka\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2s Could not install the app on the device, read the
>   error above for details. Make sure you have an Android emulator
>   running or a device connected and have set up your Android development
>   environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

I have accepted licenses using `.\sdkmanager --licenses` but no luck. I have reinstalled the sdk using the sdk manager in android studio with no luck. Anyone know what I should do?

Comment: Try to install the dependencies manually in AndroidStudio and try again

Comment: @WiFi I tried it, gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the sdkbuildtools used by Android Studio and your emulator are the same as the ones in your build.gradle file in your project folder. If they do not match then either change the build.gradle file to use the installed sdk version. What probably happened is you have sdk 27 used by your android studio and your rn project  tried to build it using sdk 26. Accepting the license will not change anything because while it's accepted it is still not used by your emulator and you Android Studio. 
Hope that helps!

Comment: Please upvote my answer if you found it useful :) Thanks!

Comment: I am now getting this error: 

`Could not run adb reverse: spawnSync C:\Users\bheka\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools/platform-tools/adb ENOENT` 

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229579/could-not-run-adb-reverse-react-native

Comment: Please start another issue, since my answer resolved the problem you asked for please accept it as an answer. 
As for the new issue you're having make sure the port is free (can be blocked by apache, skype etc) or try running on another port.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out a fix, I had to add a folder and name it "platform-tools" and adb.exe in it inside the `C:\Users\bheka\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and was resolved by fixing environment variable, ANDROID_SDK_ROOT. It was previously pointing to .../sdk/platform-tools/ and later worked by changing it to .../sdk