# Update Android SDK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-sdk-tools

I want to update my downloaded Android SDK, at present Eclipse can't able to load SDK manager so that I can pick API and download latest one as well options exist in SDK manager for updating other useful things.

So what to do for update now?

This is my current downloaded and working SDK structure, there is not direct access to SDK manager:

[image]

So what to do for updating Android SDK?

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169817/android-sdk-tools-standalone-installer

Comment: Using Eclipse for Android development has been unsupported for years.

Comment: If there is nothing holding you from switching to Android Studio, then do it. It's free :)

Comment: Android studio is completely new for me, I am Unity game developer person so nothing related to me with Android Studio and many things different compare to Eclipse at their. If become possible then I don't want to touch android studio.

Comment: @Siddharth It only took me one week to get comfortable with IntelliJ IDEA (which AS is based on.) Even when Eclipse was officially supported, I used to spend about one day a week swearing at it and marveling that a piece of software written for programmers was such a pile of garbage. Eclipse and IDEA are like night and day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android sdk tools standalone installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169817/android-sdk-tools-standalone-installer)

Answer (score 6):

The **sdkmanager** is located for you in the following location :

> sdk/tools/bin/

Now open your terminal and go to the above directory and run the following command to update all the installed packages

> sdkmanager --update [options]

And it will update all of your installed packages.
To update specific packages you can refer this link :
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager

For windows users sdkmanager is located in the following location :

> C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin