# How to run Android Emulator using Webstorm, React-native CLI on Mac 2020

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

How do I get my android emulator to execute my react-native code?

I just started using react-native.

I have installed the react-native CLI and bootstrapped an application.

I have also installed android studio and gotten the emulator running.

I ran `npm run android` it simply opens a terminal but does not kickstart the emulator.

How do I fix that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run react-native on android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577669/run-react-native-on-android-emulator)

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the React Native CLI,running `react-native run-android` (or `npx react-native run-android` if you are using npx) should be enough to build the app, launch an emulator and deploy it.