# Convert dockerfile tested in unix to windows, RUN command failing due to Permission denied

Tags: java, docker, gradle, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I have a `Dockerfile` as below, tested to work on Unix systems. My client is trying to use the same on a windows but getting a `Permission denied` error on `RUN ./gradlew clean deployNodes` step.

How do I tweak my `Dockerfile` so that it works on a Windows system as well?

```sh
# Get java8
FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim
# Get gradle
FROM gradle:4.7.0-jdk8-alpine AS build
# Start as root to update the alpine image to install bash
USER root
# Add bash
RUN apk update && apk add bash
# Move the code, as owner
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
# Assign a working directory 
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src
# Run clean build
RUN ./gradlew clean deployNodes
# Expose ports for the services
EXPOSE 8080 5005 5006 5007 5008 5009 10001 10070
# Run the application
ENTRYPOINT ["build/nodes/runnodes"]
```

#### Edit:

The error is in :

```
/bin/sh: ./gradlew: Permission denied
The command '/bin/sh -C ./gradlew clean deploynodes' returned a non-zero code: 126
```

Following this thread I have made `gradlew` an executable:
[gradlew: Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668265/gradlew-permission-denied)

Comment: this `WORKDIR /home/gradle/src` can not be the error . could you please post the error from the build command

Comment: @LinPy I am trying to get the stack trace from the client. Meanwhile, he said that it was on step 7. Which could be `RUN ./gradlew clean deployNodes`.. Do you think this could cause the error? I will get back with the stack trace within a few hours

Comment: yes this could be `RUN ./gradlew clean deployNodes`

Comment: @LinPy Thanks. I will update the question soon!

Comment: make sure also that they have all required files in the same folder as dockerfile so that will work `COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src`

Comment: @LinPy Yes, the files are part of the repository, so I am sure about that. The `Dockerfile` is in the root directory of the repository

Comment: What's the actual error message?  If it's a Windows host, can you check that the `gradlew` script has Unix (LF-only) line endings?

Comment: @DavidMaze I do not have a Windows environment to test it on and I am not at all familiar with Windows. I ran `file gradlew` and got `gradlew: a /usr/bin/env sh script text executable, ASCII text`

Comment: Which docker version does your client use?

Comment: @LinPy I have updated the question. The line which we were suspicious about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add:

```
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix
RUN dos2unix gradlew
RUN chmod +x gradlew
RUN ./gradlew clean deployNodes
```

Comment: I have changed the `gradlew` permissions into the repository as executable