# Error while building release Flutter app in AppCenter

Tags: android, flutter, continuous-integration, visual-studio-app-center

When I build my Flutter app in AppCenter, for Android, I receive this error, what does it "**Gradle does not have execution permission.**", it's not on my machine, its on AppCenter's :

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            0.1s
[!] Gradle does not have execution permission.
    You should change the ownership of the project directory to your user, or move the project to a directory with execute permissions.
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
##[error]/bin/bash failed with return code: 1
##[error]Bash failed with error: /bin/bash failed with return code: 1
##[section]Finishing: Post Clone Script
##[section]Starting: Checkout
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. For me worked `git update-index --chmod=+x gradlew` as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49074196/3573390