# How to install Java in an Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: java, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

One step in my Azure DevOps pipeline requires Java to be installed on the agent.

I found the "Java Tool Installer" task here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/java-tool-installer?view=azure-devops

This looks, however, more like a SDK installer. I only need a Java runtime environment. I am looking for something like the Python installer task:

```
steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.6'
```

Is there anything for Java getting close to this?

Comment: For others (like me) who were looking to install JDK8 on self-hosted agent: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71113705/894565

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there anything for Java getting close to this?

Test with the `Python installer task`, this task is used to specify a specific python  version via setting the environment.

To achieve a similar purpose with Java, you could set the `Java_Home` and `Path` variable during the runtime.

You could add a powershell task at the first step.

Here is an example:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=JAVA_HOME]$(JAVA_HOME_11_X64)"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH]$(JAVA_HOME_11_X64)\bin;$(PATH)"
```

The `$(JAVA_HOME_11_X64)` variable is an environment variable.

You could check this variable with the script `env | sort`. Then the supported value will list in the output.

For example:

[image: Java version]

In this case, the JAVA_HOME variable will be set as the expected value.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Great! I also did not get that several Java versions are preinstalled on the agents, and listed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 2):

Since [Azure supports Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops), I would simply go for docker:

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pr:
- main
- releases/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'

container: adoptopenjdk:latest

steps:
- script: ./gradlew check
```

Comment: I'm getting permission deny: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668265/gradlew-permission-denied

Comment: ##[error]File not found: 'docker'