# Gradle 6+ Daemon Cannot accept connection from remote address

Tags: gradle, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04, gradle-daemon

Ever since upgrading to gradle 6.x (tested on 6.0, 6.0.1, 6.1.1, 6.2.2) on one EC2 instance running ubuntu 18.04, I can't get a gradle daemon to start, they just endlessly create and crash with the Error "Cannot accept connection from remote address is host `<some-ip>`" where that IP is the EC2 host private ip. I've seen similar issues online, but no working suggestions on how to fix it. I've tried allowing that IP and the port mentioned in the logs with ufw, but no dice.

Comment: I have the same issue; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046319/android-studio-failed-gradle-execution-cause-broken-pipe/32777685#32777685 describes a workaround that worked but is unacceptable for the current server.

Comment: @EricY.Theriault that workaround is for Fedora, Ubuntu uses a different firewall and iptables rules, but maybe that'll help me figure out a workaround