# Error occurred configuring root project android

Tags: java, cordova, android-gradle-plugin

I don't understand the error message I got, or how to resolve it.  When I am trying to build my project, I see the following error:

> ```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+.
> Required by:
>      :android:unspecified
>    Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
>       Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
>          Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
>             The target server failed to respond
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> ```

I'm using Cordova with the Ionic framework.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Your question came to me in a review queue to help improve questions.  I've done some of this: corrected formatting (see [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)), along with title and grammar ***To really make it answerable*** you need to show what else you've done (e.g. followed the advice to run with `--info`, `--stacktrace`, `--debug` or [checked this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626026/) and why that hasn't helped. Good luck!

Comment: Very thank you for your help.it's already fixed. I wried the function in the answer. should I close the question or do somethingelse?

Comment: No problem.  Posting an answer is the right thing to do.  No need to put the thank you to me in the actual answer, although I appreciate your comment :)  Just edit your answer to say something like: "In my case, the problem was solved by updating my SDK and then rebooting.  It may have been that the original error (target server failed to respond) was a network error, or the SDK update may have solved it"

Answer (score 1):

This is a Java SSL connection error I solved on Github [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6362#issuecomment-189852511).

You need to add the appropriate SSL certificate to the java keystore for java accept the connection.

Work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

already fixed. @J Richard Snape thank you for your help with my question.
I updated my sdk and reboot my pc. it's worked. 
it looks like is the network isuue.

Answer (score 0):

On my case it was because I was behind a proxy. After I connected on a open network, it worked fine.