# Error: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'

Tags: android, gradle

i've just installed the latest version of Android Studio Bundle with SDK
but i couldn't run even its "hello world" default simple program and when ever i tried to run program it just keep saying **Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.**
and here is the complete gradle console log:

> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature. :app:preBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72211Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42211Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugJava
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugSources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:preDexDebug FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   >     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   >     non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 4.734 secs

i tried with jdk version 7 and jdk 8 (32bit-win8)

i know there are similar topic and questions but none of them counldn't solve my problem

Comment: Run it with `--stacktrace` as the message suggests to see in detail what's failing.

Comment: @EricMartinez : it is my first experience of using android studio and i don't know how and where to do that, you mean using CMD and this command, ' gradle -s assembleDebug ' ???

Comment: Check out this thread, it shows you how to run it with `--stacktrace` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626026/android-studio-and-gradle-build-error