# Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

Tags: android, apache-poi, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to integrate apache POI library with my android application. For that i have added apache poi jar files in to my libs folder and using "compile files" I'am compiling through build.gradle. But when I do gradle sync there is no problem in it. After doing gradle sync, when I try to run the application I am gettinf the error Execution Failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.

I have seen the following similar problems, but no use.

[Error: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832573/error-execution-failed-for-task-apppredexdebug)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437049/android-studio-gradle-execution-failed-for-task-apppredexdebug

Following is my gradle dependency:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile files('libs/poi-3.12-20150511.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.12-20150511.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511.jar')
compile files('libs/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar') 
}
```

Error message :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
  Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe'' 
  finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Gradle Console Output :

```
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:preDexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlSimpleList$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlSimpleList$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlSimpleList$2) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlSimpleList$2) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$2) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$2) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$3) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$3) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$SchemaTypeLoaderCache$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$SchemaTypeLoaderCache$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","position":{},"original":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","position":{},"original":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","position":{},"original":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","position":{},"original":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","position":{},"original":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","position":{},"original":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class."}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","position":{},"original":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.validator.ValidatingXMLInputStream$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","position":{},"original":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.validator.ValidatingXMLInputStream$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an"}
```

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 22.982 secs

Comment: it happens because of conflicting libraries. when there is a library used twice you get errors.

Comment: You can see my dependency file, i didnt use any libraries twice,. @MohammedImranN

Comment: Why aren't you letting gradle download the libraries for you?  For example, use the following for the poi library:

    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.12'

This will let gradle manage the dependent libraries (which may be the problem).

You can also use gradle commands to see the duplicate libraries.

    gradlew dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your clue buddy, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck with this error for past two days, finally i deceided to search for alternate way to create excel sheets in android application.

I have tried using "aspose" library, which really easy to use compared with "apache Poi" and "jxl" libraries.

Links for "Aspose" libraries and how to use in android projects.

http://www.aspose.com/android/total-component.aspx

https://github.com/asposecells/Aspose_Cells_Android

Thanks for everyone who helped me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you try the following sequence (in that order): invalidate cache & restart => gradle sync => gradle clean => gradle build?
2. In File => Project Structure => SDK Location:  Did you set the JDK location to point to valid install of JDK 7 ?
3. Do you have this in the module's build.gradle which is triggering the error:

   ```
   android {
       ...
       compileOptions {
           sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
           targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: i have tried clean, Invalidate caches and gradle sync. Everything is fine, gradle sync is successfull. But when try to run the application, getting this problem. @Phileo99

Comment: Nope, I dont have the "compileOptions" module in my build.gradle file. 
Anyways, I dropped using Apache Poi library to create excel files. Instead of that, i tried with "Aspose.jar" which solve my problem.