# Android Gradle Errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

`money_of_my` is my module. When I run Gradle Task `:money_of_my:dependencies`, some errors occur.

Gradle Bulid Message says:

```
Information:Gradle tasks[:money_of_my:dependencies]
Error:\--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
Error:\--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.0.0
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0 (*)
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0 (*)
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.0.0
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0 (*)
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0 (*)
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.0.0
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0 (*)
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0 (*)
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.0.0
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0 (*)
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0 (*)
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:\--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0
Error:|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.0.0
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Error:+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0 (*)
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0 (*)
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 (*)
Information:BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Information:Total time: 1.766 secs
Information:73 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

As a picture:

[image: as picture]

I don't know about this and my app can run on my Genymotion. I want to ask why those errors happen and if I ignore them, what problems will surface?

bulid.gradle as follow:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chase.cn.money_of_my"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        renderscriptTargetApi 24
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
         exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.github.SwiftyWang:TopToastBar:1.1.4'
    compile files('libs/libammsdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/xUtils-2.6.14.jar')
    compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-2-4.jar')
    compile 'com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.4.4'
    compile 'me.shaohui:bottomdialog:1.1.9'
    compile 'com.wonderkiln:blurkit:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file.

Comment: I have posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following this solution. It might be helpful for you.
[Android Studio: Where is the Compiler Error Output Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633956/android-studio-where-is-the-compiler-error-output-window)
For your question 'why those errors happen and if I ignore them, what problems will surface?', I think following explanations will be helpful.
[Android Studio and Gradle build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626026/android-studio-and-gradle-build-error) and [Gradle Goodness: Continue Build Even with Failed Tasks](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/12/gradle-goodness-continue-build-even.html)

Comment: I have read these, My app can build successfully but when I run ':money_of_my:dependencies' still error.