# Build fails inside Android studio (command line works)

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I've got a problem building inside Android Studio.

Error I get is:

```
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip'.: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip'.
```

It works just fine to build if I execute `gradlew compileDebug` from command line but not inside Android Studio.

I've got this error once before, at that time it worked after restarting Android Studio, but not any more.

I've tried to set GRADLE_HOME as suggested here [Gradle home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580776/android-studio-new-project-can-not-run-throwing-error/17066135#17066135) and using a local distribution. I've also tried to remove the .gradle cache in C:\Users\XXX folder as suggested at other pages and "Invalidate caches/Restart" inside Android Studio.

It was working yesterday and I haven't changed the build files or added any new files.

What can be wrong? Please help!

Comment: Future readers may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18869864/) helpful.