# Android Studio 0.2.9 unable to create new project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm unable to create new projects in Android Studio after updating to the newest 0.2.9 version. I am using OSX and get the following error message: 
"Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence."

After checking the log, I see the following:

```
2013-09-17 13:38:29,891 [ 110887]   WARN - .project.GradleProjectImporter - com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:204)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:144)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver$1.fun(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:136)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver$1.fun(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:126)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:161)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:76)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:87)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:44)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:53)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:130)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:407)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$1.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:454)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:468)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$6.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:279)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:207)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:675)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:434)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:151)
```

I have the same problem with older projects too. Did anybody had this problem? How should I fix it? I see that the problem is with Gradle, but unfortunatelly I am not a practiced Gradle user :/

EDIT: I also see this:

```
Gradle 'TodoNotesAppProject' project refresh failed:
         Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip'.
         A problem occurred configuring project ':TodoNotesApp'.
         A problem occurred configuring project ':TodoNotesApp'.
         Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':TodoNotesApp:classpath'.
         Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:4.0.
         Required by:
         TodoNotesAppProject:TodoNotesApp:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.7 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:22.2.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:22.2.0
         com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
         Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence
```

EDIT2 (the build.gradle file):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Could you post in the contents of your build.gradle files?

Comment: I updated the question with it

Comment: File with full details at b.android.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got an answer on G+ from Tor Norbye. 
If I change the

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
```

line in the build.gradle to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.6'
```

It works as a temporary solution.

The answer was the following:

"I'm not a Maven/Gradle expert but it sounds like there are some corrupted binaries in your repository? In any case, that dependency makes it look like you're using the new version of the Android plugin (0.5.7). Maybe try using 0.5.6 (by specifying it in your build.gradle rather than 0.5.+) as a temporary workaround? (Not a permanent solution since there are other important fixes in 0.5.7 and going forwards, so we need to figure out the real problem.)﻿"

Comment: Thanks for this. It works for me. I really don't know why this error appears sometimes.