# Android Studio 0.2.13 missing dexFile

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android Studio, and have updated it to the latest Version 0.2.13. My problem is that I am not able to debug my project anymore. The error I get from gradle:

```
“Gradle: A problem was found with the configuration of task ':AdcSampler:packageDebug'.
> File 'C:\ArneTFS\AndroidStudio\AdcSampler\AdcSampler\build\libs\AdcSampler-debug.dex' specified for property 'dexFile' does not exist.”
```

And, I have checked, the file is not there! I thought the result of packing the file into Android format should produce the dex file in that path?
My projects used to work before I updated to the latest version. I have tried to uninstall Android Studio and installed an older version. But, now that didn’t work either. Yesterday, it suddenly started to work again, by magic. I could even update to latest version (0.2.13), and everything was fine. So I happy went to bed, but when I tried to run my project this morning, then it had stopped working?!

So now I have tried to generate the most simple project, using just default values. Compiling works fine, but when it comes to making the .apk file in the Gradle packageDebug task, then I get the same error message as shown above.
Beneth is my gradle file:

Any tips?

### Regards Arne

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I spent several hours searching for solutions, all that is written here [Android Studio new project can not run, throwing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580776/android-studio-new-project-can-not-run-throwing-error) didn't help me.

But I found what **my** problem is - the environment variable USERNAME. I think, apparently, the installation of some software changed my USERNAME variable from JOHN to SYSTEM. You can check it out as:

> `echo %USERNAME%`

in command prompt.
I changed the USERNAME and oops! - BUILD SUCCESSFUL!
Hope, this helps.