# Android studio don't let me create a project with api version 10

Tags: android

When I go to create a project in the theme options just appears holo themes, there isn't a "none" option, and the minimun api to use those themes is the API 11

I have the last version of android studio.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465049/changing-api-level-android-studio

Comment: I have the same issue. Does not help.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file `{Install_Path}\android-studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidApplication\template.xml` and add 'none' as an option for 'baseTheme' parameter

Duplicate of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597298/cant-create-android-project-with-api-level-10-because-no-compatible-themes-are/19777592#19777592) question.